# Сдвинуть столбец двумерной матрицы вниз

Tags: java

Всем привет.

Такой вопрос- стоит задача в двумерном массиве при обнаружении 0 сдвинуть весь столбец вниз (удалить ноль, сдвинуть содержимое верхних ячеек в низ, дырку которая появится сверху заполнить нулем).

```
    for(int i=9;i>0;i--){
        for(int j=9;j>0;j--){
            if(field[i][j]==0){
              //  Тут еще один цикл сделать, или как лучше?
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сдвигать прямо в этом цикле:

```
for(int i=9;i>0;i--){
  int shift = 0;
  for(int j=9;j>0;j--){
    while(j-shift>=0 && field[i][j-shift]==0) {// обрабатываем последовательные нули
      shift++;   
    }
    if (shift > 0) {
      // берём значение выше, если есть, иначе заполняем нулями.
      field[i][j] = j-shift>=0 ? field[i][j-shift] : 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется массив `a` размерностью `M x N`, то можно в циклах это сделать следующим образом

```
for ( int j = 0; j != N; j++ ) // цикл по столбцам
{
    int k = M;
    for ( int i = M; i != 0; i-- ) // цикл по строкам для выбранного столбца
    {
        if ( a[i-1][j] != 0 )
        {
            if ( k != i ) a[k-1][j] = a[i-1][j];
            --k;
        }
    }

    while ( k != 0 ) a[--k][j] = 0;
}
```

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int a[][] =
        {
            { 1, 1 },
            { 0, 2 },
            { 2, 0 },
            { 0, 0 },
            { 3, 3 }
        };

        for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++ ) System.out.printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
            System.out.println();;
        }

        System.out.println();;

        for ( int j = 0; j != a[0].length; j++ )
        {
            int k = a.length;

            for ( int i = a.length; i != 0; i-- )
            {
                if ( a[i-1][j] != 0 )
                {
                    if ( k != i ) a[k-1][j] = a[i-1][j];
                    --k;
                }
            }

            while ( k != 0 ) a[--k][j] = 0;
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++ ) System.out.printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
            System.out.println();;
        }

        System.out.println();;
    }
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
1 1 
0 2 
2 0 
0 0 
3 3 

0 0 
0 0 
1 1 
2 2 
3 3
```

Comment: @MDobroch ТО, что вы показали, просто не имеет смысла. Изначально переменная c инициализируется 0, а затем в цикле while стоит условие while ( c != 0 ). Ну, так этот цикл никогда не будет выполнен.

Comment: Действительно... туплю. Спасибо!